# Group by ID and Show all results from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-by

I have 2 tables

```
tabcats - Cat_Id, Cat_Name
tabnews - News_Id, News_Name, Cat_Id
```

So I'm trying to make a select on database and return all results but using

```
Group by Cat_Id
```

so my results was supposed to be

let's say I have 3 Categories and 5 News

Results

  ### Cat_Name 1
- News_Name (1)
- News_Name (2)

  ### Cat_Name 2
- News_Name (3)
- News_Name (4)

  ### Cat_Name 3
- News_Name (5)

I read something about using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but I don't get this clearly.

Comment: Im stuck with this, actually i just did a regular query to select all results, but just list all results by ID DESC.

Comment: Are you trying to output HTML like you have in your question (`<ul>`) or was that just for display in the question?

Comment: My problem is the query michael, nothing about the html.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be clear about yourself. What I supposed that you tried to do is select some counts of latest news,isn't it? Try query similar to this one: *The below query Find the course ID, semester, year and title of each course offered by the Comp. Sci. department*

```
    select section.course_id, semester, year, title from section, course where section.course_id = course.course_id  and dept_name = ‘Comp. Sci.'
```

Ordering can be done as follows:

```
return(mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM tabNews GROUP BY news_id DESC LIMIT *counts*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to list all news together with cat name sorting by cat name follow by news name.

```
SELECT News_Name,Cat_name from tabNews n left join tabCat c on n.cat_id=c.cat_id 
ORDER BY c.cat_name,n.news_name
```